# How to refer to dynamic sheet in Excel VBA instead of Sheet Name - Instead of "Sheet16", i want to refer to the ActiveSheet

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, worksheet

## How to refer to dynamic sheet in Excel VBA instead of Sheet Name - Instead of "Sheet16", i want to refer to the ActiveSheet, please see below

Sub Macro1()

```
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet16").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet16").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("M1:M12"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet16").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: change "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet16")" to "ActiveSheet".

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change it to (ActiveSheet.Name)

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `ActiveSheet` (as well of that of `ActiveCell`, `Selection` and the like of) should be avoided in favor of that of variables of proper class (e.g.: `Worksheet`, `Range`) as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy ' handle only relevant cells
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    
    Dim newSh As Worksheet
        Set newSh = ActiveSheet ' set the currently active sheet to the 'newSh' variable of 'Worksheet' class
        
        With newSh ' reference 'newSh' variable
        
            .Paste
            
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter
        
            Dim keyRng As Range
                Set keyRng = .Range("M1:M12") ' set M1:M12 cells range of the referenced sheet as the one for sort keys
                
                With .AutoFilter.Sort ' reference 'Sort' property of 'Autofilter' object of referenced sheet
                    With .SortFields ' reference 'SortFields' object of referenced 'Sort' property
                        .Clear
                        .Add2 Key:=keyRng, _
                                   SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    End With
                    
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With

        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly fine for me :)

```vb
Sub Sortieren()

lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

        
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
     Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Sort.SortFields.Clear
     Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("N1:N" & lr), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
        
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```